# How to put bounding box only after the entire object is completely within region of interest?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box

[This is the image i get..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo1e2.jpg)

I have set the left side of red line vertically as the region of interest. Trained a model to detect licence plate where boxes contains the detected object coordinates within ROI. The bounding box appears even before the entire object is within the region of interest. I want the bounding box to appear only after the entire object is within the ROI. This is my code for the bounding box.

```
            x, y, w, h = boxes1[i]
            label = ""
            color = (0, 0, 255)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
```

Comment: Your shared code does not help. Your problem is in ```boxes1[i]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the rectangle only if `x + w` is at the left side of the red line.

```
red_line_x = 200    # for example
x, y, w, h = boxes1[i]
if (x + w) < red_line_x:
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. Also could you please share What condition should i use in addition to this so that the bounding box doesn't appears in left side (after half of licence plate gets out of frame in left) ?

Comment: I think for that you need to consider the ratio between `w` and `h`.  If the license plate is not fully visible in the image, then the `w` is smaller that the case it if fully visible.